# Create two new columns when splitting words with hyphen in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, that has a column that contains two words split by a hyphen. I  would like to create two new columns with each split value.

```
 Value                    Type

 ABC-California           Low 
 DEF-New York             Low
```

Desired output:

```
Value1     Value2        Type

ABC        California    Low
DEF        New York      Low
```

What I am doing:

```
df.replace('-', ' ').split(' ')
df['Value1'] = df.replace('-', ' ').split(' ')
```

However, I am not sure how to create the new columns. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one line solution:

```
df[['Value1', 'Value2']] = df['Value'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting this error: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable - Is it something I need to do

Comment: @Lynnette I guess `expand=True` is needed inside `split`.

Comment: You prob meant: `df['Value1'], df['Value2'] = df['Value'].str.split('-', 1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, @Lynnette, you can retry with `expand=True`

Comment: Is `['Value']` still not present?

Comment: It is present, you can remove it with [df.drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: Then it's not a one line solution anymore :D

Comment: @d_kennetz the question was about "creating new columns"

Comment: I see, I'm just being picky. It also has an "expected output" which the one-liner doesn't match. I still upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.concat([df['Value'].str.split('-', expand=True), df['Type']], axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'Value1', 1:'Value2'})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Value1      Value2 Type
0    ABC  California  Low
1    DEF    New York  Low
```